# Phone number firebase authentification

Tags: android, firebase

Im using android in a project which requires a phone number authentification and Im wondring if there is anyway to check if a phone number is verified in firebase ?

Comment: As far as I know, a user is only signed in once their phone number of verified. Before that, they're not signed in.

Comment: This question is circular - if a phone number is in the database it would have been verified, and only verified phone numbers would exist in the database. So what are you asking? Can you provide a use case? If you want to query for a persons phone number, a simple solution is to also store the users phone number in a */users/uid_x/phone_number:* and that node would only be written when a number was verified.